# IE6 and fieldset background color?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

Hey, I'm having some difficulty with CSS and IE6 compatibility.

**URL**: http://bit.ly/dlX7cS

**Problem #1:** I put a background image on the fieldset around `Canada` and `United States`. In IE6 and IE7, the background bleeds above the border-top of the fieldset.

So, I found a fix. It is applied only to IE browsers, and moves the legend up a few pixels, aligning the background correctly.

```
<!-- Fix: IE6/IE7, Legends -->
<!--[if lte IE 7]> 
    <style type="text/css">
        fieldset {
            position: relative;
        }
        fieldset legend {
            position: absolute;
            top: -0.5em;
            left: 0;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

This fixes IE7. But in IE6, it seems to make my legend for `Canada` vanish completely. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: It seems when I remove `width` from my first fieldset, the label appears again. Oye, I don't know what's going on, but I'll take the freebee.

Comment: what version of IE6 are you using?

Comment: I just downloaded 'Microsoft Expression Web 3 SuperPreview for Internet Explorer'. Someone on another StackOverflow thread recommended it. It's great. Seems to be working properly now.

Comment: I just checked it on clean install of IE6 using my virtual machine and it looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE6 fieldset fix: http://www.gunlaug.no/tos/moa_18.html

For the iframe bug try setting an overflow:hidden for IE6. (you can do it like `_overflow:hidden;`
(underscore is a ie only hack)

Next time split two different questions - it's easier for others searching for same problem.

Comment: `Overflow:hidden` isn't helping. I still have discrepancy of 3 pixels.

Comment: OK, I fixed the iframe/google map. I just got rid of the margin-right that was separating my two floats. And instead of floating my map left, I floated it right. Now the extra pixels are being subtracted from the margin, which has 15 more pixels to spare. That was simple enough lol. I'm still missing my `Canada` label in IE6 though.