# Group Box in IceFaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces, icefaces-2

I want to achieve something like this in Icefaces.  HTML has a legend tag which helps. Is there any way to use that tag in IceFaces ? If not, how can we do this in IceFaces ? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fieldset element just represents a set of form controls, you can do this:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Display:</legend>
    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{saveDVDBean.title}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="gf1" itemLabel="GodFather I" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="gf2" itemLabel="GodFather II" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="gf3" itemLabel="GodFather III" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: It would be good to explain that JSF in the end will just render plain HTML, so there's no rocket science mixing plain HTML with JSF components.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Ravi. "fieldset" is defined in HTML 5.  I use IE-8, and html 5 test scores just 43 points as of today. And I am sure my clients use older versions of IE. Is there any other way to achieve this ? Time being I have put border: 1px solid is stylesheet. But this wont allow me to put the text as shown in the above pic.

Comment: fieldset is also present in HTML4 just a few attributes were added in HTML5 like the disabled, name and form attributes and it should work well in IE6. You can check the differences [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html4-differences/). There are some known styling issues in IE6 but you can easily fix them. See als0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453182/ie6-and-fieldset-background-color